# Teradata, transactional data where columns have individual update dates

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm working on a Teradata query where I'd like to find the latest value for multiple columns. Each data column is related to a date column (update date).
The header of my table should help understand my issue:
ID Attr_1 Attr_1_Update_Dt Attr_2 Attr_2_Update_Dt Attr_3 Attr_3_Update_Dt

I need to select Attr_1, Attr_2 and Attr_3 for the latest update date of each attribute (for each ID).
I've already thought of running individual ranks (by update dt) for each of the attributes and then join them into a single table. But I don't think this is too sophisticated (more over when I have 8 attribute columns).

Hope the above is enough for helping me. Looking forward to hearing from you.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get your result.

You might apply FIRST_VALUE for every additional attribute:

```
select
   Attr_1, Attr_1_Update_Dt,
   first_value(Attr_2) over (order by Attr_2_Update_Dt DESC),
   max(Attr_2_Update_Dt ) over (),
   ...
   first_value(Attr_n) over (order by Attr_n_Update_Dt DESC),
   max(Attr_2_Update_Dt ) over ()
from myTable
qualify row_number() over (order by Attr_1_Update_Dt DESC) = 1 -- only 1 row
```

This requires an extra STATS-step in Explan for each attribute, resource usage might be high when the table is large.

In that case normalizing your table might improve performance, either:

```
select 1 as attr#, Attr_1, Attr_1_Update_Dt from myTable
union all 
select 2 as attr#, Attr_2, Attr_2_Update_Dt from myTable
...
union all
select n as attr#, Attr_n, Attr_n_Update_Dt from myTable
```

or a CROSS JOIN to a table with the numbers 1 to n in it (probably more efficient):

```
select 
   num as attr#, 
   case when num = 1 then Attr_1 end,
   case when num = 1 then Attr_1_Update_Dt end,
   case when num = 2 then Attr_2 end,
   case when num = 2 then Attr_2_Update_Dt end,
   ...
   case when num = n then Attr_1 end,
   case when num = n then Attr_1_Update_Dt end
from myTable 
cross join
  (
    Select returning "num" from 1 to n
  ) dt
```

Or using TD_UNPIVOT or UNPIVOT in newer releases...

Then it's a simple

```
select *
from 
 (
   normalizing Select
 ) as dt
qualify
   row_number()
   over (partition by num
         order by Attr_1_Update_Dt DESC) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to see you storing your data in a normalized manner. Until that is done you will be cursed by needing more complex queries to perform tasks like this.

A way to deal with the data as is would be to use the GREATEST() function but for some reason only known to Teradata developers this function doesn't accept dates, but they may be cast to integers which it does accept. It's also necessary to avoid NULLs. This can give you the most recent date per row, and from there you can use ROW_NUMBER() to arrive at the rows with the most recent date per ID.

```
WITH cte AS (     SELECT 
                         ID
                       , Attr_1
                       , Attr_2
                       , Attr_3
                       , CAST(GREATEST( 
                                CAST(COALESCE(Attr_1_Update_Dt, date '1900-01-01') AS INT)
                              , CAST(COALESCE(Attr_2_Update_Dt, date '1900-01-01') AS INT)
                              , CAST(COALESCE(Attr_3_Update_Dt, date '1900-01-01') AS INT)
                              , CAST(COALESCE(Attr_4_Update_Dt, date '1900-01-01') AS INT)
                              , CAST(COALESCE(Attr_5_Update_Dt, date '1900-01-01') AS INT)
                              , CAST(COALESCE(Attr_6_Update_Dt, date '1900-01-01') AS INT)
                              , CAST(COALESCE(Attr_7_Update_Dt, date '1900-01-01') AS INT)
                              , CAST(COALESCE(Attr_8_Update_Dt, date '1900-01-01') AS INT)
                         )as date) as maxdate
                  FROM yourtable)
SELECT
       ID
     , Attr_1
     , Attr_2
     , Attr_3
     , maxdate
FROM (
      SELECT
             ID
           , Attr_1
           , Attr_2
           , Attr_3
           , maxdate
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID
                               ORDER BY maxdate DESC) as rn
      FROM cte
      ) d
WHERE rn = 1
```

I can't be accurate on the performance of this approach, it is probably best suited to a moderate table size. If your table is very large then I really would explore options to normalize the data.